# iOS 5 and iOS 6 UITabBarController MoreNavigationViewController rotation

Tags: ios, ios5, uitabbarcontroller, ios6

My project is based on UITabBarController with multiple UINavigationContollers. I am adjusting app to support rotation in iOS 6. I have made subclass of UITabBarController so that I can block rotation. That works perfect. But there is problem with MoreNavigationViewController. On iOS 5 it rotates and on iOS 6 it does not. My goal is to block it. I have to support all orientations (in Info.plist) because I am using MPMoviePlayerViewController which sould adjust to rotation. Is there a way to subclass MoreNavigationViewController?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone will have the same situation this is what I have done to solve it:

1. Info.plist support all orientations
2. In custom subclass of UITabBarController I have added this method

   ```
   - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{
           return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation); 
   }
   ```

Works both iOS 5 and iOS 6.